# sonar starts and then stops running after 15 seconds without displaying any error

Tags: sonarqube, ubuntu-14.04, sonarqube5.1

I have installed sonar on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (which I am running inside windows using vagrant) by following a tutorial [here](http://dev.mamikon.net/installing-sonarqube-runner-on-ubuntu/)

And my sonar.properties file is below

**/opt/sonar/conf/sonar.properties**

```
sonar.jdbc.username=sonar
sonar.jdbc.password=sonar
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
sonar.web.host=127.0.0.1
sonar.web.context=/sonar
sonar.web.port=9000

sonar.jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
sonar.jdbc.validationQuery=select 1
sonar.jdbc.dialect=mysql
sonar.jdbc.maxActive=20 sonar.jdbc.maxIdle=5
sonar.jdbc.minIdle=2
sonar.jdbc.maxWait=5000
sonar.jdbc.minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=600000
sonar.jdbc.timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=30000
```

Once after installing I restarted, started the sonar as below

```
/opt/sonar/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh restart
/opt/sonar/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start
```

Now I have checked the status of the sonar as below

```
/opt/sonar/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh status
```

and output is ***SonarQube is running.***

and after some time like 15 seconds, I have checked the status again and now the output is ***SonarQube is not running.***

I don't what's the reason that causing sonar to shut down immediately because its not displaying any error

sonar.log(**/opt/sonar/logs/sonar.log**) file output

```
--> Wrapper Started as Daemon
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2017.07.28 06:47:48 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonar/temp
2017.07.28 06:47:48 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /opt/sonar/temp/sq-process8071013234782021313properties
2017.07.28 06:47:48 INFO   es[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting es
2017.07.28 06:47:48 INFO   es[o.s.s.EsSettings]  Elasticsearch listening on 127.0.0.1:9001
2017.07.28 06:47:49 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1501224467799] version[1.7.5], pid[5493], build[00f95f4/2016-02-02T09:55:30Z]
2017.07.28 06:47:49 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1501224467799] initializing ...
2017.07.28 06:47:49 INFO   es[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1501224467799] loaded [], sites []
2017.07.28 06:47:49 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.env]  [sonar-1501224467799] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/sda1)]], net usable_space [34.3gb], net total_space [39.3gb], types [ext4]
2017.07.28 06:47:50 WARN   es[o.e.bootstrap]  JNA not found. native methods will be disabled.
2017.07.28 06:47:52 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1501224467799] initialized
2017.07.28 06:47:52 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1501224467799] starting ...
2017.07.28 06:47:52 INFO   es[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1501224467799] bound_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}, publish_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}
2017.07.28 06:47:52 INFO   es[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1501224467799] sonarqube/a-DrjveQTd6cOLiDMQGFPA
2017.07.28 06:47:55 INFO   es[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1501224467799] new_master [sonar-1501224467799][a-DrjveQTd6cOLiDMQGFPA][vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64][inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1501224467799}, reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
2017.07.28 06:47:55 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1501224467799] started
2017.07.28 06:47:55 INFO   es[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1501224467799] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
2017.07.28 06:47:55 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
2017.07.28 06:47:55 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonar/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.35.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /opt/sonar/temp/sq-process7630170265596703695properties
2017.07.28 06:47:56 INFO  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2017.07.28 06:47:56 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatContexts] Webapp directory: /opt/sonar/web
2017.07.28 06:47:57 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9000"]
2017.07.28 06:47:57 INFO  web[o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2017.07.28 06:47:58 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl] SonarQube Server / 5.6.4 / 52298794f1a34a4fd713ff8d441a0c13432e40a9
2017.07.28 06:47:58 INFO  web[o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
2017.07.28 06:47:58 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "20 sonar.jdbc.maxIdle=5"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:223) ~[commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
        at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.initDataSource(DefaultDatabase.java:92) ~[sonar-db-5.6.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.db.DefaultDatabase.start(DefaultDatabase.java:70) ~[sonar-db-5.6.4.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer$1.start(ComponentContainer.java:320) ~[sonar-core-5.6.4.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
--> Wrapat org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
Launchinat org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
Wrapper at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
  Copyriat org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
        at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
2017.07.at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767) ~[picocontainer-2.15.jar:na]
2017.07.at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:141) ~[sonar-core-5.6.4.jar:na].awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMat org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]r=/opt/sonar/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonat org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.start(Platform.java:216) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
2017.07.at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startLevel1Container(Platform.java:175) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
2017.07.at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.init(Platform.java:90) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
2017.07.at org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:43) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]
2017.07.at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
2017.07.at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
2017.07.at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32])]], net usable_space [34.3gb], net total_space [39.3gb], types [ext4]
2017.07.at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
2017.07.at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
2017.07.at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_131]g ...
2017.07.at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_131], publish_address {inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]}
2017.07.at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_131]
2017.07.at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_131]224467799] new_master [sonar-1501224467799][a-DrjveQTd6cOLiDMQGFPA][vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64][inet[/127.0.0.1:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1501224467799}, reason: zen-disco-join (electe2017.07.28 06:47:58 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
2017.07.28 06:47:58 ERROR web[o.a.c.c.StandardContext] Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
2017.07.28 06:47:58 WARN  web[o.a.c.l.WebappClassLoaderBase] The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread: INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method).JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)erIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -javaagent:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonar/lib/jdbc/mysql/my com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:43)265596703695properties
2017.07.28 06:47:58 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9000"]
2017.07.28 06:47:58 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started/sonar/web
2017.07.28 06:47:58 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 9000ttp-nio-127.0.0.1-9000"]
2017.07.28 06:47:58 WARN  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Fail to start webselector for servlet write/read
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Webapp did not startarQube Server / 5.6.4 / 52298794f1a34a4fd713ff8d441a0c13432e40a9
2017.07.at org.sonar.server.app.EmbeddedTomcat.isUp(EmbeddedTomcat.java:84) ~[sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]06/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
2017.07.at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.isUp(WebServer.java:47) [sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]to listener instance of class org.sonar.server.platform.PlatformServletContextListener
java.lanat org.sonar.process.ProcessEntryPoint.launch(ProcessEntryPoint.java:105) ~[sonar-process-5.6.4.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.app.WebServer.main(WebServer.java:68) [sonar-server-5.6.4.jar:na]:1.8.0_131]
2017.07.28 06:47:58 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9000"]
2017.07.28 06:47:59 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9000"]
2017.07.28 06:47:59 INFO  web[o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol] Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-127.0.0.1-9000"]ommons-dbcp-1.4.jar:1.4]
2017.07.28 06:47:59 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is stopped92) ~[sonar-db-5.6.4.jar:na]
2017.07.28 06:48:00 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopping ~[sonar-db-5.6.4.jar:na]
2017.07.28 06:48:00 INFO   es[o.s.p.StopWatcher]  Stopping processhod) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
2017.07.28 06:48:00 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1501224467799] stopping ...
2017.07.28 06:48:00 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1501224467799] stopped
2017.07.28 06:48:00 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1501224467799] closing ...
2017.07.28 06:48:00 INFO   es[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1501224467799] closed
2017.07.28 06:48:00 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I have checked whether mysql is running or not as below and it was running and up

```
 mysqladmin -u root -p status
Uptime: 2781  Threads: 1  Questions: 122  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 48  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 41  Queries per second avg: 0.043
```

So finally I didn't understand what makes sonar to shut down after some time once it was started, and what changes to make in order to run sonar continuously and where to debug?

Answer (score 2):

You have a missing line break here:

```
sonar.jdbc.maxActive=20 sonar.jdbc.maxIdle=5
```

Sonar can't parse the `maxActive` option because everything after the first `=` is parsed as integer. This obviously fails:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "20 sonar.jdbc.maxIdle=5"

Simple solution:

```
sonar.jdbc.maxActive=20
sonar.jdbc.maxIdle=5
```

Comment: Sorry that's a typo, but it was as it is as you mentioned in actual properties file and still it was not working

Comment: If it still isn't working after the typo, please post a new question with updated config and the new error message. @shivakrishna